# Keycloak: Granted scope not saved for federated users

Tags: java, openid-connect, keycloak

### Problem:

I have a Keycloak realm with a mixed user base.
Some users are native (native users), some are provided trough a custom User Storage SPI implementation (federated users).

When I perform an OIDC login, Keycloak asks to approve 4 scopes (test-client, profile, email, roles).
The request is performed with scope **openid**. Keycloak transforms it to these four scopes.
**test-client** is the client name. There is no actual client scope with this name showing in the admin UI.

---

Using a **native user** everything works fine. I approve and the login completes successfully.

Having a look at the user consents confirms that everything is ok.
[image]

---

Using a **federated user** the login fails with the following message.

```
[invalid_scope] Client no longer has requested consent from user
```

Looking at the users consent we see that the **test-client** scope is not being added.
[image]

Trying to exchange the code for a token, produces a fitting error in the Keycloak log

```
11:06:31,964 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-10) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=torment, clientId=test-client, userId=f:ff4c66e5-2a6f-465c-8418-200648a49973:dfb_user, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=not_allowed, grant_type=authorization_code, code_id=418dfa66-b4c8-4481-b46d-ceac97e65b39, client_auth_method=client-secret
```

All further login tries will ask to approve only the missing **test-client** scope, but it will never be added to the consent.

---

### Question:

1. Why does this happen?
2. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not passing scopes list as query parameters in the URL constructed to initiate Keycloak authentication. Please check your authentication URL.

```
 Set<ClientScopeModel> clientScopes = TokenManager.getRequestedClientScopes(scopeParam, client);
        if (!TokenManager.verifyConsentStillAvailable(session, user, client, clientScopes)) {
            event.error(Errors.NOT_ALLOWED);
            throw new CorsErrorResponseException(cors, OAuthErrorException.INVALID_SCOPE, "Client no longer has requested consent from user", Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
```

Your error is coming from [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/endpoints/TokenEndpoint.java). 
If you take a look at [TokenManager.getRequestedClientScopes](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/TokenManager.java) (line number 523), it checks whether user still has granted consents to all requested client scopes. 
So, I think you can try to add all the scopes in request URL. For example, http://keycloak_url/auth/realms/.......?....scope=openid%20test_client%20profile.....
I hope it helps.
[image]Additionally, you can enable this setting on Keycloak Client (Scopes tab).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time look at my question.

Comment: The problem is that the test-client scope is never saved to the given consent for a federated user (but for native users it is).
The error after that is expected.

-

I have tried to request the four scopes individually, instead of using the openid scope. But that doesn't make a difference.

-

The only thing that made it kinda work was deactivating "Consent required" for the client, since this avoids the check altogether.
Login will be successful, but that kinda defeats the purpose...

Comment: Have you tried to send all four scopes together, instead of individually?

Comment: I have. Ultimately the problem is only that the test-client scope is not saved when I approve it.
No matter how I request it.

Comment: It is listed for approvement, but not saved when I do approve. The other three are.

Comment: I just checked how we have implemented it. It seems like we store all the query parameters in browser cookie. When the IdP returns to your application with a response, you can fetch the scopes from the cookies. Please check if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but his isn't about the client at all.
Keycloak does not save the test-client scope as approved, while I have approved it.
That's what the screenshots of the Keycloak Admin UI show.
There is no way to influence this as the client. It's 100% about the Authorization Server (Keycloaks OAUTH2-Role in this scenario), not doing what it should.